# Python 3. How to find all possible consecutive character swaps of a string

Tags: python, string, list, function, recursion

I am trying to find a way to be able to get a list of all possible consecutive character swaps in a string. I must do this without any fancy tools like itertools, which makes it harder. For example:

```
x = 'costumye'
```

Should produce the list:
['ocstumye', 'csotumye', 'cotsumye',...(since there are many possibilities), 'costumey']
My code:

```
x = 'costumye'
possible_w = []
def swap(wurd):
    wurd = list(wurd)
    for i in range(len(wurd)-1):
        reg = x[i], x[i+1]
        reg = x[i+1], x[i]
        print(reg)
swap(x)
```

This code alone gets the correct different instances where words should swap places. The bad thing is that they are simply tuples, which makes sense. I am now having trouble changing the whole word for every swap, and appending each swap instance into my list to get the final list with all possibilities.

Comment: How does `reg` relate to the output you want?  And why do you assign to it and them immediately overwrite that?

Comment: Oh I was just testing the swap with the indices. I overwrite it because that is what I do to swap the consecutive letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write the code to swap a given location `i` with the next letter.  You have four element in the new word:

- the letters up to position `i`
- the letters at `i+1` and `i`
- the rest of the word

Simple concatenate them in order -- give the word `x` and the position `i`

```
swap_word = x[:i] + x[i+1] + x[i] + x[i+2:]
```

Now, you need to loop through this for all swappable positions:

```
for i in range(len(x)-1):    # Don't try to swap the last letter with the one after
```

Finally, accumulate results.  Start with an empty list; append the new word on each iteration:

```
swap_list = []
for i in range(len(x)-1):    # Don't try to swap the last letter with the one after
    swap_word = x[:i] + x[i+1] + x[i] + x[i+2:]
    swap_list.append(swap_word)
```

Can you finish from there?

---

Great.  Now, if you want the "higher plane" Pythonic answer, your entire function reduces to a single list comprehension:  "return a list of *this* string expression, for each position in the valid range"

```
return [ x[:i] + x[i+1] + x[i] + x[i+2:] for i in range(len(x)-1) ]
```

Comment: Yeah I think I got it

Comment: Yeah I was able to implement it into my function. Thanks so much for clearing up the last and prior letter issue too.